# Should your clients pay for your payment transfer fees

Tags: payment-terms

I'm from a third world country where the luxury to accept payments from most popular payment gateways like PayPal doesn't exist to get payment transfers done cheap from my clients to me. I lose a significant amount of my earnings due to transfer fees. Would it be ethical to pass the burden of paying for all the transfer fees to my client in addition to the monetary compensation I am paid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most companies like PayPal have it in their agreements that you can not do this. But, to be honest, just factor it into the price and know you'll be taking home X-Payment Provider's Take. Just and idea.